# Normal and Abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A, B subgroups of G, B/A abelian. Show that BN/AN is abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134071/a-b-subgroups-of-g-b-a-abelian-show-that-bn-an-is-abelian)

Let A, B, N be subgroups of a group G such that A $\triangleleft$ B and B/A is Abelian.  Also suppose N $\triangleleft$  G. Prove that AN $\triangleleft$ BN and that BN/AN is abelian.

I'm awful at these kinds of questions and never know what I need to do!

I know $AN \subseteq BN$ as $A \subseteq B$ and AN and BN are subgroups as N $\triangleleft$  G.  Now I take $x=an \in AN$ and $y=bm \in BN$  $m,n \in N$ . Then $yxy^{-1} = bmanm^{-1}b^{-1}$  I change this to $bmab^{-1}bnm^{-1}b^{-1}=bmab^{-1}n'$ with B/A abelian I can change this to $bmb^{-1}an' = m'an'$.   I'm missing some step to get it in the form $an$ but don't know what?  For the second part I'm completely stumped so any help appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question we had yesterday.  I'll just look it up.

Comment: Since $N$ is normal, for any $x\in G$ and any $n\in N$, there exists $n'\in N$ such that $nx = xn'$. So you can take $m'an'$ and rewrite it as $(m'a)n' = (am'')n' = a(n'')$, with $n''=m''n'$.

Comment: Sorry my bad, thanks!